# Set IPV4 address in docker_gwbridge when deploying a Docker swarm

Tags: database, docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

I am trying to deploy a Galera cluster using Docker swarm. Then I want to connect to the servers from my host machine.

Now I know I can use `docker_gwbridge` network to connect from my host machine. But In the `yaml` file, I can not specify the IP address for any `bridge` network when deploying a stack of services.

I can set IPs for the overlay network though.

How can I make sure every time I deploy the stack, the containers get same IP on `docker_gwbridge` network?

Comment: Why not publish their ports? Or why not connect to them from another container?

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks, but I am looking for a network solution. Not something like forwarding ports.

Comment: @rnbguy Could you find a workaround to set a static IP address for docker_gwbridge interface of containers in a swarm?

Comment: no I did not. I ended up using docker-compose with a script to scrap the network ip addresses.